# Custom context menu items in file manager? (execute with custom bash script shortcut)

Tags: bash, files, hashsum

Is there a way in any Linux GUI file manager to create a custom shortcut to a bash file to be executed using the selected file(s)?

Example: *Create hash sums of this file.*

Bash script: `makehashsums.bash`

```
(md5sum $@
sha1sum $@
sha512sum $@
cksum $@
sum $@ ) >>$@.hashsums.txt
```

These are not all available hashsum algorithms, but the most common ones.

**If possible, it would be great if it is supported for multiple files.**

How can I add such a custom option to the context menu of a Linux file manager? (Is there one that supports this feature?)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Desktop env it should be fairly simple to add your own scripts to the Open-with dialogue.

[image]

For the script itself, you just cycle through the command line arguments. `~/bin/hashies`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Don't want to get upset by
# whitespace in filenames.
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

# Cycle through inputs
for file in $*
do
    # Get hashes for the files
    # Store per target file.
    (
        md5sum $file
        sha1sum $file
        sha512sum $file
        cksum $file
        sum $file
    ) > ${file}.hashsums.txt
done

# Probably don't need to bother with
# restoring the input field separator
# as the sub-shell is about to die.
IFS=$oldIFS
```

Comment: That should be `for file` to work with whitespace in file names (it's equivalent to `for file in "$@"`, which is the correct way to loop over arguments). And you don't need to override `IFS`.

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks. But can it also be added to the direct context menu that gets shown immediately after the right mouse click?